# "I finally had a love that fit--custom made for me, by me." -- Does "that fit" work?

Tags: grammar

- *I finally had a love that fit – custom made for me, by me.*

I found this sentence in a book, and I don't know what function of *fit* is.
Is it a verb with the relative pronoun, that? If it is, shouldn't be *fits* instead of *fit*?

Comment: To be strictly grammatical it should be 'fitted' to match 'had' in the past tense, but this is a form of informal street-speak. The use of 'fit' in this way is very common, particularly in US English. it's not strictly correct but it is colloquial. Using 'fit' instead of 'fitted' gives the quotation an energy, edge and a sense of 'cool' that 'fitted' would not have done.

Comment: could you repeat the sentence that your Q is about in the body of the Q? I am not sure which parts of the headline are the actual sentence

Comment: "Fit" as past tense or past participle of "to fit" seems to be [a North American thing](https://grammarist.com/usage/fit-fitted/) although even there both "fit" and "fitted" are found. Not sure if there's a regional distribution or another reason for variation.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I think you may be confused as to what a relative pronoun is? The word "that" _is_ functioning as a relative pronoun in the sentence in the question, but _not_ in "I like that" (where it's a demonstrative pronoun).

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the explanation! It helped me a lot.